# asp.net debug compilation = false throws javascript error

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, c#-2.0, asp.net-2.0

i am getting Javascript error after i modified the web.config [debug compilation = false ]

i have embedded javascript in my code using webResource

[assembly: WebResource("ClientModels.js", "text/javascript")]

Previously it has debug compilation = "true" and it was working fine but after modification 
Compilation debug ="false" targetFramework ="4.0"

Thanks

Comment: What is the JavaScript error?

Comment: as i am having embed javascript in my code behind files, some function  in the js file is not included. ERROR =Object doesn't support property or method i have enabled the jscript on my browser so got error in the below piece of code 'add_EditModeChanged' [component.add_EditModeChanged(this._onEditModeChangedHandler);